# How to use SlidesSnippet tool probably for google slides api python

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-slides-api

So I am trying to automate creating google slides using SlidesSnippets

(https://github.com/gsuitedevs/python-samples/blob/master/slides/snippets/slides_snippets.py)

I have all api credentials handles and access into my api service but having a hard time understanding how to fully link the code with my slides directory

(https://docs.google.com/presentation/u/0/?tgif=d)

I have taken the code in the github and re-wrote the **init** section shown below:

```html
class SlidesSnippets(object):
    # def __init__(self, service, drive_service, sheets_service, credentials):
    def __init__(self):
        # self.credentials = credentials
        self.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

        scope = [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        ]
        self.credentials_scoped = self.credentials.create_scoped(scope)
        http = self.credentials_scoped.authorize(httplib2.Http())

        # self.service = service
        self.service = build('slides', 'v1', http=http)

        # self.drive_service = drive_service
        self.drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

        # self.sheets_service = sheets_service
```

The comments are what was originally in the class function and then I replaced it with my details.

So when I run this code:

```html
import slides_snippets as slides

slides_init = slides.SlidesSnippets()
slides_dict = slides_init.create_presentation("TEST")
```

I get this response that looks like a slides id tag and then when I go to

and when I try and go to that directory with the tag in it

(https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/**OUTPUT_SLIDE_ID_FROM_create_presentation**/edit)

It asks for me to request control and the powerpoint is nowhere to be seen in my slides drive.

Did I mess anything up in my SlidesSnippets **init** function?

Answer (score 0):

I used some function to init it. Maybe it can help you.

class SlidesSnippets(object):
    def **init**(self):
        self.drive_credentials = None
        self.slides_credentials = None

```
def drive_service(self,gdrive_SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']):
    '''gdriver token'''
    if os.path.exists('drivetoken.pickle'):
        with open('drivetoken.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            gdrive_creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not gdrive_creds or not gdrive_creds.valid:
        if gdrive_creds and gdrive_creds.expired and gdrive_creds.refresh_token:
            gdrive_creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', gdrive_SCOPES)
            gdrive_creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('drivetoken.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(gdrive_creds, token)

    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=gdrive_creds)
    self.drive_service,self.drive_credentials = drive_service, gdrive_creds
    return self.drive_service,self.drive_credentials

def slides_service(self,slides_SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations']):
    '''slides token'''
    if os.path.exists('slidetoken.pickle'):
        with open('slidetoken.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            slides_creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not slides_creds or not slides_creds.valid:
        if slides_creds and slides_creds.expired and slides_creds.refresh_token:
            slides_creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', slides_SCOPES)
            slides_creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('slidetoken.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(slides_creds, token)

    slides_service = build('slides', 'v1', credentials=slides_creds)
    self.slides_service,self.slides_credentials = slides_service, slides_creds
    return self.slides_service,self.slides_credentials
```